# CoreData - Relationship One to Many - Data Model

Tags: ios, core-data, relational-database, entity-relationship, iphonecoredatarecipes

[image]

Here is my Core Data structure . I have three Entities `Room` `Key` and `KeyRoomMap` . Now I have two attributes in `Room` and `Key` . I want the `ID` attribute of both of them should be associated with the third table `KeyRoomMap` and there is also more one element `SuggestedTestPlan` in the `KeyRoomMap` .

My Questions are

1. This is the structure like - SQL Tables here. But I feel this is the
   wrong structure in core Data . I want to join `keyID` and `roomID` 
   with some relationship with KeyRoomMap . How can I do it like if I
   add keyID and roomID , it should be automatically added in
   KeyRoomMap ?
2. there are more keys for each rooms . so key1 , key2 are associated
   with room1, key3 is with room2 and key4,key5,key6 are with room3
   .How can I make such relationship here ?

-----------------------Edited and Added

Actually my confusion also starts with if key1 and key2 are associated with Room1 . I can join them with the one to many relation there . but the keyroomMap entity was defined for saying that key1 and key2 are associated with Room1 . If I dont make this table then only on the basis of relations out of so many keys how should I say that ??

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it looks like you are planning it like SQL tables.

From your explanation it sounds like:

- A Room can have many keys

and

- A Key can unlock one room

Therefore I would say the relationship on your Room entity would be 'keys' and this is a to-many relationship. Keep in mind in core data you need to set up inverse relationships also so the corresponding relationship on the Key entity would be room and would be a to-one relationship.

I have included the datamodel diagram as an image below.

[image: Room - Key Model]

I'm not really sure what your purpose is for the KeyRoomMap? Could that suggestedTestPlan property exist on Key or Room instead? It seems as though KeyRoomMap entity has two relationships in that for a KeyRoomMap to exist it must have a corresponding Room and Key both of which are to-one relationships. I've included a possible diagram for that but without more info I can't be sure.

[image: Room - Key - RoomKeyMap Model]

**EDIT:** Otherwise is suggestedTestPlan a property that could be derived or calculated based on the other Entities? ie. Fetched properties https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW7

Comment: Hey Daniel Thanks for your answer , But I was really thinking do I need any attribute like this identifier ? because I was using roomID and locationID as a primary key in my core data , Now if I join them with the relation there wont be any ID needed . right ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I had assumed that identifier would be something specific to your room rather than database id (ie. in a hotel room identifier 409). If thats not the case you can just access them through their relationship. self.room.keys will give you a set of keys for that Room. Or if you have a Key self.key.room will give you its corresponding Room.

Comment: Also if you use the Xcode model generators it will create methods for you on your model classes to add and remove objects. Xcode > Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass. This will generate Room.h and Room.m for you with methods such as addKeyObject:(Key *)value; and addKeys:(NSSet *)values;

Comment: My Dilemma again is  what if the data goes repetitive ?? Dont we need something unique in every table ??

Comment: I added more data , Please also see that whenever you are free ?